# Вёрстка сайта: как убрать непонятные поля между блоками и границами браузера?

Tags: html, css

Каков оптимальный метод вёрстки сайта с растяжимыми элементами (шапка, футер и любые другие), при котором эти элементы вплотную соприкасаются с окном браузера?

Приведу конкретный пример. На шаблоне сайта ниже шапка и футер с заливкой; между их растяжимыми краями и браузера не должно быть никакого пространства.

[image: Шаблон]

А вот моя шапка сайта: как видите, между краями шапки и окна браузера у меня поля, хотя `margin` шапки равен 0 по всем сторонам.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сверстал я это так:

```
header{
    position: realtive;
    min-width: 1000px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #3CBAC8;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Другие сайты в своём браузере я смотрел - никаких полей нет.

Я слышал о таком методе вёрстки, как псевдо-распорки, которое применяется для растяжимых по ширине окна сайтов, но я прошу привести решение с минимумом тэгов и классов.

Comment: html,body{padding:0; margin:0} ?

Comment: Скачать и подключить файл сброса стилей normalize.css
https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: вы для *{margin:0; padding:0;} сделайте, и код выложите , ни ясно и не видно что вы наделали

Comment: Прошу прощения, всё заработало при body{margin: 0}. Отвечу сам на свой вопрос; подредактируйте, если что-то неточно сказал.

Comment: Opera 38.0.2220.31, Chrome 51.0.2704.103 m, FireFox 47.0, IE11, Edge - default css для body { margin: 8px;};

Answer (score 2):

По-видимому `<body>`, в отличие от других объектов, таких как `<header>` или просто `<div>`, имеют ненулевые маргины по умолчанию, по крайней мере сверху и по обе стороны. Решение проблемы очевидное:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: W3C плачут по вам (по вас).

Comment: uorypm самое прикольное что body{margin:0:} пишится везде

Comment: @LenovoID так пишут как раз из-за того, что W3C рекомендовало делать по дефолту для BODY отступы в 8 пикселев(-ей). Хотя не спорю, очень многие просто копипастят не понимая что делают. Это печально. Даже сам ТС не понял почему так - *по-видимому* - хотя ему скинули ссылку на полезный материал.

Comment: Сейчас очень популярен flat-дизайн, пример которого я привёл в своём вопросе, а там редко делаются поля у body если вообще делаются.

Comment: @Gurebu Bokofu, отступы есть по дефолту. Я же не предлагаю их оставлять. Лишь хочу показать, что вы не совсем поняли, почему они там есть.

Comment: Хорошо, благодарю Вас за объяснение.

Answer (score 0):

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Лучше подключить файл сброса стилей [godlike.css](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/godlike.css)